# How can I check last number of recursive step and create an empty element for the recursive step less than n?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Input,
n=6 and String = "TEST "{text1}" "{equal}" "{text2}"

I'm using the following xslt code,

```
<xsl:template name="SplitString">
<xsl:param name="text"/>
<xsl:param name="n"/>

<xsl:if test="$n > 0">
<xsl:element name ="P">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after($text, '&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
</xsl:element>

<!--recursive call -->
<xsl:call-template name="SplitString">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&quot;')" />
    <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1" />
</xsl:call-template>        
</xsl:if>
```

</xsl:template>

The output I get is,

```
<P>text1</P>
<P>   </P>
<P>equal</P>
<P>   </P>
<P>text2</P>
<P/>
```

Is there a way to get the following output for n=6 and String = "TEST "{text1}" "{equal}" "{text2}" ?

```
<P>test1</P>
<P>equal</P>
<P>test2</P>
<P/>
<P/>
<P/>
```

Comment: Your statement `String = "TEST "{text1}" "{equal}" "{text2}"` is confusing because it's not clear which quotes are part of the string itself. If the first quote is part of the string, then the result you get cannot be the result you show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```
<xsl:template name="SplitString">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="n"/>
    <xsl:variable name="token" select="normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after($text, '&quot;'), '&quot;'))" />
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$n > 0 and $token">
            <P>
                <xsl:value-of select="$token" />
            </P>
            <xsl:call-template name="SplitString">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&quot;')" />
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>        
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$n > 0 and $text">
            <xsl:call-template name="SplitString">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '&quot;')" />
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n" />
            </xsl:call-template>        
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$n > 0">
            <P/>
            <xsl:call-template name="SplitString">
                <xsl:with-param name="n" select="$n - 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>        
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

---

**Note**: it is not good practice to use `xsl:element` when the name of the element is known in advance.

Comment: Thank you very much Michael for the answer it worked as required. I very much appreciate your suggestion. Thanks a Million!!!